# useEffect not running once I navigate back and again to the screen. Reason and solution

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

```
import { useRoute, useIsFocused, useFocusEffect  } from '@react-navigation/native'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { ScrollView , Text, View, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, StatusBar, TouchableOpacity, BackHandler} from 'react-native';
import BackBotton from '../components/UI/BackBotton';

import { useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';

import {gql, useQuery} from '@apollo/client';

import { InterstitialAd, AdEventType, TestIds } from 'react-native-google-mobile-ads';

import { incrementCounter, resetCounter } from '../store/counter';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import NetInfo from '@react-native-community/netinfo';

const QUERY = gql `
  //some query
`

const adUnitId =  TestIds.INTERSTITIAL ;
const interstitial = InterstitialAd.createForAdRequest(adUnitId);


function AdScreen({navigation}) {
  const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(true);

  const { width } = useWindowDimensions();
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(null);
  const isFocused = useIsFocused(); // Declare isFocused as state with default value null

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const counter = useSelector(state => state.counter.count);

  const { 
    params: {
      title, 
      id,
    },
  } = useRoute();

  const {data, loading,  error, refetch} = useQuery(QUERY, {
    variables: {id},
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
      setIsConnected(state.isConnected);
    });
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  const handleRefresh = () => {
    refetch();
  };
//THIS SECTION ****************************************************************************
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = interstitial.addAdEventListener(
      AdEventType.LOADED,
      () => {
        setLoaded(true);
      }
    );
  
    // Start loading the interstitial straight away
    interstitial.load();
  
    // Unsubscribe from events on unfocus
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [navigation]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackPress);

    return () => {
      backHandler.remove();
    };
  }, []);


  useEffect(() => {
    if (counter >= 5 && loaded && interstitial) {
      interstitial.show();
      setLoaded(false);
      interstitial.load();
      dispatch(resetCounter());
    }
  }, [counter, loaded, isFocused]);

  const handleBackPress = () => {
    dispatch(incrementCounter());
    return true;
  };

  return (
     <View style={styles.test}>
            <Text>{counter}, {!loaded && <Text>not</Text>},{!isFocused && <Text>not focused</Text>},{isFocused && <Text>focused</Text>},  {(loaded===null) && <Text>null</Text> } {loaded && <Text>loaded</Text>}</Text>           
        </View>
  )
}

export default AdScreen
```

useEffect() (commented as THIS SECTION ****...) doesn't seem to run once I navigate back using BackBotton component and again enter the screen. I used useFocusEffect and useEffect with isFocused, navigation variables. Nothing seems to run that useEffect once I navigate back and reenter the screen. I wanted to display ads when the backbotton is pressed 6 times or so.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using stack navigation you can set property of the screen you want to unmount inside options of navigator.screen.

```
unmountOnBlur: true
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but still useEffect is not runnig.

Comment: maybe unmountOnBlur also don't run. https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/10542

Comment: If view is inside tab navigation, then the unmountOnBlur doesn't work